# putExtra in asynchronous way

Tags: android

I would like to perform `startActivity(intent)` and `intent.putExtra()` in asynchronous way.
For example

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
    // listener for button
    public void onSomeButtonClicked(View ignored) {
        final Intent intent;
        // instantiate intent

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
            protected String doInBackground(Void... ignored) {
                // do heavy task
                return "didALotOfWork";
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String resultOfHeavyTask) {
                intent.putExtra("key", resultOfHeavyTask);
            }
        }.exexute(null);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

in the code above, I'm not sure that `putExtra` can be preceded by `startActivity`.

Is this code has any problem?
What is the best solution for passing data among activities asynchronously?

A method I came up with is that editing SharedPreference. However, I think better one may exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you most probably getting Null pointer Exception.

Initialise Intent in OnPostExecute and add startActivity in same method. Check below code

```
protected void onPostExecute(String resultOfHeavyTask) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, <class>);
    intent.putExtra("key", resultOfHeavyTask);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This should work. Cheerz

Comment: This is my current workaround and I don't like this since this approach is slow. I'm investigating a way for `startActivity` in non blocking way and pass some data later for performance. Maybe I should `execute` heavy `AsyncTask` in next activity.